# Java : JFrame Issue with Print Statement

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm facing a problem when the program runs console print the message of frame width and height with `getSize()` method but when i increase the width of frame with mouse resize.Then i want to update that print statement with that increase width.I don't know how can i do that.
Code

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {

        super("Frame");

        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Main Method

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame = new Frame();

        System.out.println(frame.getSize());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`ComponentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) to your frame and let the program print the size inside the `componentResized` method.

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(frame.getSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Or since we are overriding only one method we can use adapters

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(frame.getSize());
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are going to provide non-empty implementation to small number of methods from `ComponentListener` interface use `ComponentAdapter` instead. This adapter provides empty implementation for all methods declared in interface.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks! I just wanted to show him which other methods he can orverride inside a `ComponentListener`, and this was the easier way because Eclipse can add the unimplemented methods automatically. Of course you're right, I forgot to mention `ComponentAdapter`. (thanks for the edit)

Comment: @LuxxMiner and Pshemo thanx for help